# An object reference is required to access non-static member UnityEngine.Material.GetTextureOffset(string)

Tags: unity, c#

I am watching a tutorial where it seem to work. But in my case, I am getting this error. I get it that non-static members have to have an object. But, I don't know much about how to fix this error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AnimatedTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector2 speed = Vector2.zero; 

    private Vector2 offset = Vector2.zero; 
    private Material material;

    void Start(){
        material = GetComponent<Renderer> ().material;

        offset = Material.GetTextureOffset ("_MainTex"); 
    }

    void Update(){
        offset += speed * Time.deltaTime;

        material.SetTextureOffset ("_MainTex", offset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `Material.GetTextureOffset ("_MainTex");` in the `Start()` method.
It should be `material.GetTextureOffset ("_MainTex");`.